# Is there a rspec helper to test a validate on update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, rspec2

I am using the following validation

"validates_presense_of :column, :on => :update"

Is there a helper provided by rspec to test the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this and this is exactly what i wanted

http://remarkable.rubyforge.org/activerecord/classes/Remarkable/ActiveRecord/Matchers.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
describe ThingsController, "#update" do
  context "for a thing" do
    before do
      get :update, :id => 1
    end
    it { should validate_presence_of :your_column_name }
  end
end
```